# Run method on a different thread while listening for user input

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

How best to send method to another thread while listening for input from the user.  How best to pause/resume that same threaded method?

A very trimmed down example of the kind of thing I am trying to achieve:

```
    static int fuel = 100;
    static bool tankEmpty = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("test");

        ThreadStart fuelThreadStart = ProcessFuel;
        var fuelThread = new Thread(fuelThreadStart);
        fuelThread.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Press x to add fuel");
        string input = Console.ReadLine(); // < where should this go?
        if (input == "x")
        {
            AddFuel();
        }
    }

    static void ProcessFuel()
    {
        while (!tankEmpty)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Current fuel level: " + fuel);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            fuel -= 10;
            if (fuel < 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fuel level is low.");
            }
        }
        if (tankEmpty)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have run out of fuel")
        )
    }

    static void AddFuel()
    {
        if (fuel > 80)
        {
            fuel = 100;
        }
        else { }

        fuel += 20;
    }
```

Comment: One way is to have your ProcessFuel function in a while loop e.g while(processing == true) and have your main thread set processing to true/false to pause/resume the loop

Comment: Shouldn't ProcessFuel contain a loop?

Comment: Would the loop need to be run on a different thread? (as not to block the UI).  If so, how?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Loop added, not sure it is in the right place, though?  I don't know where Console.ReadLine needs to be in this kind of scenario...

Comment: Pull the console.clear to before the while loop

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd moving teh console.clear just means the console gets filled with the current status of the fuel level.  As it stands I can only appear to add fule once and then the console.readline is never hit again.

Comment: put a loop around the readline too